# Flash video player streaming

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4

Is that possible to streaming a video from a certain time.

For an example i want to start the video from the time of 1.23 min 
but its always start from 0 only

time= something in millisecond;

I gave **`nsStream.seek(time)`** but even its start from 0 only.This is because the stream is not available for that time.

So can we start video streaming from mentioned timing is that possible.

I don't want to use FMS or Red5 for this.I know there is a possibility using server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but in order to enable seeking you will need a server that supports streaming/psuedo-streaming.  If you don't want to use your own dedicated media server (eg., *FMS* or *Red5*), and you don't plan on using a CDN (eg., *bitgravity*, *limelight*, etc), another option is to use a plugin for regular web servers (eg., *Apache*, *lighttpd*, *nginx*, etc) to enable psuedo-streaming.

For example, take a look at [H264 Streaming Module](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki).

Once you enable support for streaming on the server, you need to determine the start parameter the server uses.  For the H264 Streaming Module the syntax is:

```
"http://your.server.com/video.mp4?starttime=83"
```

would begin the video from 1:23, assuming that 1) a keyframe exists there and 2) the encoding of the video itself is hinted.

Whether this adds out-of-the-box support for the **NetStream seek()** method, I can't say outright.  I presume since some major Flash-based streaming players (eg, *Flowplayer*, *JWPlayer*) support HTTP psuedo-streaming, either the **seek()** method does simply work or the code to support HTTP psuedo-streaming isn't that complicated.  Both cited players are open source.

Either way, I think the scope of your question is adequately answered.

Comment: Can u give some sample codes to implement  this task on red5 that will be very much helpful for me.

Because i need seek functionality.Please let me know

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Sankaranarayanan - There are plenty of other questions on SO that address Red5 specifically.  Additionally, Red5 has a bunch of code examples in it already.  If you still can't find what you need from those resources, then I suggest you ask a different question, since in this one you explicitly said that you did **not** want to use Red5.

Comment: Initial i thought to refuse red5 and fms.since i want to use seek there is no more possibilities other than red5 or fms to buffer from the seek point.Thats why i asked the sample anyway thanks for your help